# How to add time picker in HTML5 which have HH:MM format with selected Dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker, timepicker

I searched everywhere but I'm not satisfied by the answer. At last I'm posting here to get the answer.

I have two `datepicker` and `time picker` `textbox` which displays 12:00 format with AM & PM.

Here I want to calculate the TOTAL `time` which includes number of days and given time.
I want to add those time and display it in another text box. I need it in **HH:MM** format. I don't want seconds as my `time picker` `textbox` shows only **HH:MM** which is enough for me.

I tried many methods to add but i'm not getting the exact **time** value.

Below is my HTML code

```
<input type="date" id="opening_date">
<input type="date" id="closing_date">
<input type="time" class="time" id="garage_out_time">
<input type="time" class="time" id="garage_in_time">
<input type="text" id="total_hours">
```

Below is my script code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function ConvertDateFormat(d, t) {
    var dt = d.val().split('/');
    return dt[0] + '/' + dt[1] + '/' + dt[2] + ' ' + t.val();
}
$(".time").change(function () {
    var start = new Date(ConvertDateFormat($('#opening_date'), $('#garage_out_time')));
    var end = new Date(ConvertDateFormat($('#closing_date'), $('#garage_in_time')));
    console.log(start, end);
    var diff = new Date(end - start);
    var days = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
    var hours = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / 1000 / 60 / 60);

    var total = (days * 24) + hours;

    var startTime = document.getElementById("garage_out_time").value;
    var endTime = document.getElementById("garage_in_time").value;
    var s = startTime.split(':');
    var e = endTime.split(':');
    var endtime = parseInt(e[1], 10);
    var starttime = parseInt(s[1], 10);
    var min = endtime + starttime;
    var minutes = min ;
    var minhours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes = minutes % 60;

    total = total + minhours;
    if(minutes > 9){
    $("#total_hours").val(total+":"+ minutes);
    } else {
        $("#total_hours").val(total+":0"+ minutes);
    }
});
});
```

Above code is working for some extent BUT for example when I select 8:12 AM to 8:12 PM , the result I'm getting is **12:32** where answer should be **12:00**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating things somewhat. Your ConvertDateFormat() function already gives you what you need, so why are you parsing the time again? Try the code below (with thanks to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/544429/5976413) answer)

```
var start = new Date(ConvertDateFormat($('#opening_date'), $('#garage_out_time')));
var end = new Date(ConvertDateFormat($('#closing_date'), $('#garage_in_time')));
console.log(start, end);
var diff = new Date(end - start);
var mins = Math.floor( diff /    60000 %   60 );
var hours = Math.floor( diff /  3600000 %   24 );
var days = Math.floor( diff / 86400000        );
console.log('days='+days+' hrs='+hours+' mins='+mins);
var totalHours = (days * 24) + hours;
var minsStr = (mins < 10) ? '0' + mins : mins;
$('#total_hours').val(totalHours + ':' + minsStr);
```